# How can I change the color of build output in a shell window?

Tags: build-process, highlighting

I have a build process which runs from a batch file.  It produces a large volume of text.  Sometimes it prints the word "Error" or "Warning" followed by a message.  The errors and warnings are getting lost among a sea of text.

Can I highlight those words in a different color, maybe in a dos window, or a cygwin shell window, possibly by piping them through some string manipulation program before posting them to the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is to pipe the output to a shell script and then colorize using [ANSI codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Unfortunately ANSI support on Windows (at least in XP) is pretty lacking and you have to use [some workarounds](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/UserTips/CommandPrompt/CommandInterpreterAnsiSupport.html) to get ANSI to show up in a DOS window; it will work under cygwin, but that might cause problems with your batch file.